# Margin/Gap & rearranging buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to move the text "MENU" to the center and the glyphicon to the center as well, putting the glyphicon to the left of "MENU", but when I move "MENU" to the center, it covers everything to the left and right in the entire navbar and I can barely click the glyphicon anymore.

And my second question is,
how do I get rid of this margin or gap or whatever it is?:

[image]

Navbar:

```
    <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="my-navbar" style="font-family:Webdings;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header" id="oneDiv">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" id="iconButton">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="color:white"></span>
                    </button>

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><font color="white">MENU</font></a>
                </div><!-- Navbar Header -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse" align="center">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="firstOne">
                        <li><a href="#" id="designProcess" role="button" id="designProcess">Design Process</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="profile" role="button" id="profile">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="contactInfo" role="button" id="contactInfo">Contact Info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="list-inline" id="secondOne">
                        <li><a href="#" class="socialicon"><img src="facebook.png" hspace="30"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="socialicon"><img src="twitter.png" hspace="30"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="socialicon"><img src="instagram.png" hspace="30"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End Container img src="twitter.png"-->
        </nav><!-- End navbar -->
```

Comment: Solved the toggle thing

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer? So you can help other people with the same problem too :)

Comment: Sure! I'm just gonna finish the rest first, almost solved all of it.